# How to make a key binding that will jump over the code completion in sublime unless it's a {} or []

Tags: sublimetext3, keymapping

I found a great keybinding that jumps over sublimes code compeletion by hitting enter here's the link: [quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-skip-the-cursor-past-the-end-of-autofilled-parens-and-braces-in-Sublime-Text-2). My code in my keymap file is:

```
// BEGIN keymaps for skipping to the end of " ) and ] code compeletion
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[)'\"\\]]", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]   
},
// END keymaps for skipping to the end of " ) and ] code compeletion
```

and it defintely works how I'd like...most of the time. For example if I'm typing in some javascript:

```
function(p1, p2|)|
hitting enter..^.^
```

and I hit enter when the cursor is at the first carrot then it will jump over to the second carrot which is what I want. However, there's another case which is when you open up, say square brackets in a sublime settings file.

```
[|]|
.^.^
```

Now because of the keymapping the cursor jumps over the right square bracket, when in reality what you want is to insert a new line like:

```
[|
.^
    |
....^
]
```

and move the carrot from the first to the second carrot, just like the behavior that happens when you create a javascript function:

```
function myFunction(){|
    | <-- cursor tabbed over
} <--curly on bottom
```

My problem is I don't really understand regex that well yet, or how to use them in combination with keymaps in sublime. Really what I need to figure out (I think) is how to insert some sort of conditional into the keymap that basically just checks:

```
if (next char is a ] and the char before it is a [)
then don't do any completion hoping
else do exactly like the keymap is already set up to do
```

How would I go about doing this? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the functionality to work when the cursor is inside parentheses `()` but not when inside square brackets `[]`. If that's the case, simply change this line:

```js
{ "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[)'\"\\]]", "match_all": true },
```

to this:

```js
{ "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[)'\"\]", "match_all": true },
```

All I did was change the `"operand"` from this

```js
"^[)'\"\\]]"
```

to this

```js
"^[)'\"\]"
```

by removing

```js
\]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. It's actually not that I want it to work with parenthesis or brackets it's more like: specifically for square brackets how can I make it work (that is jump over the bracket) when the brackets aren't right next to each other like: `[some code|]` but not work (that is open up a newline) when the brackets are right next to each other like: `[|]`. The vertical pipe is supposed to represent where my cursor is. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Hey Matt, just wondering if you've had a chance to take another look at this yet. I'm still trying to figure it out myself, and I would definitely appreciate it if you found a way :)